# Using a lot of if statements, can't I just use a loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am learning some javascript. At the moment I have created a working script of which I think the code can be a lot smaller/smarter then what I have created.

What I have:
I have 5 divs with 5 different ID's. The div with the ID: foundationPile has a couple of playing cards stacked. The HTML looks like this:

```
   <div id="foundationPile">
       Card pile
   </div> 
       <div id="discardPile">
       Foundation 1
   </div>
    <div id="discardPile2">
       Foundation 2
   </div>
    <div id="discardPile3">
       Foundation 3<
   </div>
    <div id="discardPile4">
       Foundation 4
   </div>
```

The code I've written does the following: when clicked on the card in the foundationPile div, there is a check if discardPile1 is empty or (if there is a card) check if the card is lower then the current card. If so, push the card to that pile, if not, check the second Pile etc etc.

To do this I have created code with a lot of if statements:

```
function play( card ){  
    if( discardPile.length ){
        var lastDiscard = discardPile[discardPile.length-1];    

        if( card.val == lastDiscard.val+1 )
            discard( card );
            else if( discardPile2.length ){ //NEW START2
                var lastDiscard = discardPile2[discardPile2.length-1];  

                if( card.val == lastDiscard.val+1 )
                    discard2( card );
                    else if( discardPile3.length ){ //NEW START3
                        var lastDiscard = discardPile3[discardPile3.length-1];

                        if( card.val == lastDiscard.val+1 )
                            discard3( card );
                            else if( discardPile4.length ){ //NEW START4
                                var lastDiscard = discardPile4[discardPile4.length-1];

                                if( card.val == lastDiscard.val+1 )
                                    discard4( card );
                            }
                            else if( card.val == 1) {
                                discard4( card );
                            } //NEW END4
                    }
                    else if( card.val == 1) {
                        discard3( card );
                    } //NEW END 3

            }
            else if( card.val == 1) {
                discard2( card );       
            } //NEW END2

    }
    else if( card.val == 1) { //NEW if empty ACE is allowd 
        discard( card );            
    }
}
```

Now isn't it possible to make my life easier by looping through the div's somehowe instead of checking each one with if statements? And if so, how to do this?

This isn't all the code, I also have the discard function. At the moment I have written 4 discard functions. These are basicly the same, the only difference is the ID's where to push the card to. I think this can be done easier too. Perhaps with just 1 discard function and replacing the nr with `this` or so? Also, how to do this?

These are my current discard functions:

```
function discard( card ){
        var el = getHtml( card );

        var card = cols[card.col].pop(); 
        var col = cols[card.col]; //NEW flip kaart eronder
        var flipCard = col[col.length-1]; //NEW flip de kaart eronder
        if( (col.length-1) > -1 ){ //NEW
                flipUp( flipCard ); //NEW
            }

        discardPile.push( card );
        card.location = 'discardPile';
        zindex( el, discardPile.length );
        if( discardPile.length > 3 )
            el.find('.back').removeClass('shadow');
        else
            el.find('.back').addClass('shadow');

        el.css("transform","translate("+discardPos.left+"px, "+discardPos.top+"px)");
    }

    function discard2( card ){ //NEW
        var el = getHtml( card );

        var card = cols[card.col].pop(); 
        var col = cols[card.col]; //NEW flip kaart eronder
        var flipCard = col[col.length-1]; //NEW flip de kaart eronder
        if( (col.length-1) > -1 ){ //NEW
                flipUp( flipCard ); //NEW
            }

        discardPile2.push( card );
        card.location = 'discardPile2';
        zindex( el, discardPile2.length );
        if( discardPile2.length > 3 )
            el.find('.back').removeClass('shadow');
        else
            el.find('.back').addClass('shadow');

        el.css("transform","translate("+discardPos2.left+"px, "+discardPos2.top+"px)");
    }

    function discard3( card ){ //NEW
        var el = getHtml( card );

        var card = cols[card.col].pop(); 
        var col = cols[card.col]; //NEW flip kaart eronder
        var flipCard = col[col.length-1]; //NEW flip de kaart eronder
        if( (col.length-1) > -1 ){ //NEW
                flipUp( flipCard ); //NEW
            }

        discardPile3.push( card );
        card.location = 'discardPile3';
        zindex( el, discardPile3.length );
        if( discardPile3.length > 3 )
            el.find('.back').removeClass('shadow');
        else
            el.find('.back').addClass('shadow');

        el.css("transform","translate("+discardPos3.left+"px, "+discardPos3.top+"px)");
    }

    function discard4( card ){ //NEW
        var el = getHtml( card );

        var card = cols[card.col].pop(); 
        var col = cols[card.col]; //NEW flip kaart eronder
        var flipCard = col[col.length-1]; //NEW flip de kaart eronder
        if( (col.length-1) > -1 ){ //NEW
                flipUp( flipCard ); //NEW
            }

        discardPile4.push( card );
        card.location = 'discardPile4';
        zindex( el, discardPile4.length );
        if( discardPile4.length > 3 )
            el.find('.back').removeClass('shadow');
        else
            el.find('.back').addClass('shadow');

        el.css("transform","translate("+discardPos4.left+"px, "+discardPos4.top+"px)");
    }
```

Again, I think it is possible to simplify the code, I only have no idea how to do this. If you provide working code, please explain what you did and why so I can learn from it

Thanks a lot

**UPDATE:**

The divs are postioned using variable"s:

```
var wastePos = {
        'left': x_offset * (NUM_COLS-6), //NEW
        'top': 0
    };
    var discardPos = {
        'left': x_offset * (NUM_COLS-4), //NEW
        'top': 0
    };
    var discardPos2 = {
        'left': x_offset * (NUM_COLS-3), //NEW
        'top': 0
    };
    var discardPos3 = {
        'left': x_offset * (NUM_COLS-2), //NEW
        'top': 0
    };
    var discardPos4 = {
        'left': x_offset * (NUM_COLS-1), //NEW
        'top': 0
    };
```

Comment: Use [**switch()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch)

Comment: I will take a look at this, thanks

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure how you would simplify all the if statements. However, there is definitely room for optimization in your discard function. One would suffise and pass the discardPile, discardPileName and discardPos as additional parameters.

```
function discard( card, myDiscardPile, discardPileName, myDiscardPos ){
    var el = getHtml( card );

    var card = cols[card.col].pop(); 
    var col = cols[card.col]; //NEW flip kaart eronder
    var flipCard = col[col.length-1]; //NEW flip de kaart eronder
    if( (col.length-1) > -1 ){ //NEW
            flipUp( flipCard ); //NEW
        }

    myDiscardPile.push( card );
    card.location = discardPileName;
    zindex( el, discardPile.length );
    if( myDiscardPile.length > 3 )
        el.find('.back').removeClass('shadow');
    else
        el.find('.back').addClass('shadow');

    el.css("transform","translate("+myDiscardPos.left+"px, "+myDiscardPos.top+"px)");
}
```

and then you can call it as such:

```
discard( card, discardPile2, 'discardPile2', discardPos2);
```

Comment: maybe : card.location ='discardPileX' can help to reduce this code

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Tried your code, but the cards didn't move to the correct div annymore. I understand what you explained about the paramters except the myDiscardPile one. You dont use it in the code? I also see I forgot something about the DIV positions. I use variables for this. This is perhaps whhy the myDiscardPos doesnt work? Updated my code above

Comment: myDiscardPile is the array. I corrected the answer. It is used with the push command.